# how i can hide some category from author admin panel?

Tags: categories, admin

i want author can not see some category from author admin panel but administrator can see that.how i can hide some category?my site http://techjagot.com ..

here show some function.php code

```
<?php

// Theme Settings Page
require_once(TEMPLATEPATH . "/theme-settings.php");

// Theme Styles
require_once(TEMPLATEPATH . "/theme-styles.php");

// Theme Widgets
require_once(TEMPLATEPATH . "/theme-widgets.php");

// Load Custom Post Options for Write Post and Write Page
require_once(TEMPLATEPATH . "/theme-metaboxes.php");

// Load Theme Javascript
require_once(TEMPLATEPATH . "/theme-js.php");

// Theme Image Functions
require_once(TEMPLATEPATH . "/theme-images.php");

// Register widgetized areas
function theme_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar(array (
        'name'=>'Sidebar-Wide - Top',
        'id'=>'widget-1',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s"><div class="widget-wrap">',
        'after_widget' => '</div></div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widgettitle"><span>',
        'after_title' => '</span></h3>',
        ));
    register_sidebar(array (
        'name'=>'Sidebar-Wide - Bottom Left',
        'id'=>'widget-2',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s"><div class="widget-wrap">',
        'after_widget' => '</div></div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widgettitle"><span>',
        'after_title' => '</span></h3>',
        ));
    register_sidebar(array (
        'name'=>'Sidebar-Wide - Bottom Right',
        'id'=>'widget-3',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s"><div class="widget-wrap">',
        'after_widget' => '</div></div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widgettitle"><span>',
        'after_title' => '</span></h3>',
        ));
    register_sidebar(array (
        'name'=>'Sidebar-Narrow',
        'id'=>'widget-4',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s"><div class="widget-wrap">',
        'after_widget' => '</div></div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widgettitle"><span>',
        'after_title' => '</span></h3>',
        ));
    register_sidebar(array (
        'name'=>'Footer Widget 1',
        'id'=>'widget-5',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s"><div class="widget-wrap">',
        'after_widget' => '</div></div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widgettitle"><span>',
        'after_title' => '</span></h3>',
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the [restrict categories plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/restrict-categories/). It lets you configure which categories are visible in the Wordpress admin, based on the user role or the individual user.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small snippet that will do the job. [Found it here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-hide-certain-categories-in-wordpress-dashboard?replies=7).

```
/*
 * Hide Specified Categories (by ID) from administrators
 */

add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse_55202_do_terms_exclusion' );

function wpse_55202_do_terms_exclusion() {
    //Where is the string 'author' you need to replace it with your users' role
    if( current_user_can('author') )
        add_filter( 'list_terms_exclusions', 'wpse_55202_list_terms_exclusions', 10, 2 );
}

function wpse_55202_list_terms_exclusions($exclusions,$args) {
    // edit 3 with your category's ID
    return $exclusions . " AND ( t.term_id <> 3 ) ";
}
```